# Passing Interface in a WCF Service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm experimenting with WCF Services, and have come across a problem with passing Interfaces.

This works:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IHomeService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetString();
}
```

but this doesn't:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IHomeService
{
    [OperationContract]
    IDevice GetInterface();
}
```

When I try to compile the client it fails on the GetInterface method. I get an Exception saying that it can't convert Object to IDevice.

On the clientside the IHomeService class correctly implements GetString with a string as it's returntype, but the GetInterface has a returntype of object. Why isn't it IDevice?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to tell the WCF serializer which class to use to serialize the interface

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(ConcreteDeviceType)]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think I understand.

Let's say I want the GetInterface method to return two different classes, SimpleDevice and AdvancedDevice, both which implements the IDevice interface.

Should I then set ServiceKnownType for both the types?

Comment: When deserializing, how does WCF know what implementing type of IHomeService to use?

Comment: Yeah, I think you got it.  You are telling WCF the possible types that implement the interface.  You can pass any type through, just as long as WCF knows that these known types implement the interface, and are serializable.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks, it works when I changed it like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(PhotoCamera))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(TemperatureSensor))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(DeviceBase))]
public interface IHomeService
{
    [OperationContract]
    IDevice GetInterface();
}
```

I also got help from this site: http://www.thoughtshapes.com/WCF/UsingInterfacesAsParameters.htm

Comment: Link is now 404, but some search engines have it cached

Comment: Frode: Don't you think that @Brian actually answered your question?

Answer (score 1):

I initially tried to pass an interface to a WCF method but couldn't get the code to work using the answers provided on this thread.  In the end I refactored my code and passed an abstract class over to the method rather than an interface.  I got this to work by using the KnownType attribute on the base class e.g.

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(LoadTypeData))]
[KnownType(typeof(PlanReviewStatusData))]
public abstract class RefEntityData : EntityData, IRefEntityData
```