# Silverlight WCF service consuming inherited types in datacontract

Tags: wcf, silverlight, serialization, datacontract

Im trying to consume a WCF service in silverlight...

What I have done is to create two seperate assemblies for my datacontracts...

1. Assembly that contains all of my types marked with data contracts build against .Net 3.5
2. A Silverlight assembly which links to files in the 1st assembly.

This means my .Net app can reference assembly 1 and my silverlight app assembly 2. This works fine and I can communicate across the service.

The problems occur when I try to transfer inherited classed. I have the following class stucture...

IFlight - an interface for all types of flights.

BaseFlight : IFlight - a baseflight flight implements IFlight

AdhocFlight : BaseFlight, IFlight - an adhoc flight inherits from baseflight and also implements IFlight.

I can successfully transfer base flights across the service. However I really need to be able to transfer objects of IFlight across the interface as I want one operation contract that can transfer many types of flight...

```
public IFlight GetFlightBooking()
{
    AdhocFlight af = new AdhocFlight();
    return af;
}
```

... should work I think?

However I get the error:

"The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error."

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you are manually creating the Silverlight assembly with corresponding types instead of using slsvcutil.exe or the "Add Service Reference" feature which will automatically generate all the types for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is possible in "normal" .NET WCF. Here is a question that talks about passing interfaces in a WCF service:
[Passing Interface in a WCF Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310160/passing-interface-in-a-wcf-service)

But I seriously doubt whether this will work in Silverlight. WCF support in SL is sketchy, to say the least. I haven't tried it though. I might be wrong.

Comment: Hi, Im happy to announce it does work :) I attributed my service as follows:

    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Flight))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(FlightLiveOps))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(FlightScheduled))]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class DispatchService

Answer (score 4):

You say that `BaseFlight` works; does your base-class name the known types?

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(AdhocFlight))]
class BaseFlight : IFlight {...}
```

You might also want to look at [`[ServiceKnownType]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx). In *general*, WCF isn't going to like the interface-based approach (`IFlight`), as it is going to want to know exactly what to expect from the data it is (de)serializing; I would expect it to work fine with the above and using `BaseFlight` on the API.

Comment: [ServiceKnownType] was the key - I added it to the service contract.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be related to a bug with serializing generic interface types in WCF as logged here.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/391260/executionengineexception-thrown-from-datacontractserializer-with-ilist-t

If this is related to your problem you'll be glad to hear that it's fixed in .net 4.0