# WCF and Interfaces

Tags: c#, wcf, interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing Interface in a WCF Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310160/passing-interface-in-a-wcf-service)

I've a problem regarding WCF and interfaces.

I've have two classes

```
public interface ICompany {
  string Name { get; set; }
  IAddress Address { get; set; }
}
class Company : ICompany {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public IAddress Address { get; set; }
}
public interface IAddress {
  string Road { get; set; }
}
class Address: IAddress {
  string Road { get; set; }
}
```

And my service returns

```
[OperationContract]
    Company GetCompany(String name);
```

But this doesn't work, I'm sure the problem is the IAddress inside the Company class, but can't this be solved somehow?

Comment: Can you provide more details than "this doesn't work". What error message do you get? When do you get it?

Comment: Please try to do a little research before posting. Just searching for "wcf interface" found the duplicate.

Comment: Not sure but Try to apply a ServiceKnownType attribute to your Webservice method for Address

Comment: can you clarify you problem? Error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes must declare as:

```
[DataContract]
class Company {
  [DataMember]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public IAddress Address { get; set; }
}
```

and your service declare and implement as:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICompanyService
{
   [OperationContract]
   Company GetCompany(string name);
}

public class CompanyService : ICompanyService
{
  public Company GetCompany(string name)
  {
     return new Company { Name = name};
  }
}
```

Only after that you can use this service.
And I recommend to read more [that](http://www.bing.com/search?q=wcf+hello+world&go=&form=QBRE&filt=all)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you need to mark your classes that need to be used by the clients with [DataContract] and [DataMemebr] all that before everything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [DataContract] and [DataMemebr] attributes on the class and methods that you want to be serializable. WCF will serialize the response to XML (most of the time) so the compiler must be able to serialize the object.

Comment: Incorrect. DataContract is not required: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921635/is-datacontract-attributes-required-for-wcf again, use ServiceKnownType (but this is duplicated)

Comment: @Polity it may not be required in some cases. that does not make my answer incorrect

Comment: Ok i'm sorry, with incorrect i ment not a solution  for this paticular problem