# Wcf Service Library interface type not being exposed

Tags: c#, wcf, interface

I've look over many examples (including [Passing Interface in a WCF Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310160/passing-interface-in-a-wcf-service)) with regards the problem I have, but until now have not found a solution.  I have a Wcf Service Library (.NET 4.0) with the following

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public bool Ping(IChannelManager channelManager)
    {
        return channelManager.Ping();
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool Ping(IChannelManager channelManager);
}

[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(TestChannelName))]
public interface IChannelManager
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool Ping();
}

[DataContract]
public class TestChannelName : IChannelManager
{
    public bool Ping()
    {
      //perform a ping
      return true;
    }
}
```

My project compiles fine.  But when I try to add it as a Service Reference from a console app, I can add it fine and try to access the method like below;

```
using (Test.ServiceClient oClient = new Test.ServiceClient())
{
     oClient.Ping();
}
```

But the problem I have is the Ping() method on the Wcf service, the interface type is coming up as object channelmanager ? Like

[image]

I tried adding [ServiceKnownType(typeof(TestChannelName ))] to the both interfaces but no luck.

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: It looks like you want there to be a magical service implementation of IChannelManager service contract? or maybe I'm reading the question wrong.. who creates a TestChannel Instance and calls the IService implementation?

Comment: Service : IService is my Wcf service.  I have a method Ping() that I want to be able to call, that will perform a different Ping test depending on which IChannelManager I pass

Comment: can you fix your client example to show this?

Comment: I updated my question to show the object type being shown

Comment: I'm guessing the Client is from a mex or a wsdl?

Comment: The ServiceReference is added using this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx

Comment: Why is `TestChannel` marked as a `[DataContract]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer will be split in two - a technical overview of why this happens - and philosophizing about why this happens.

first technically If you have a look at:

```
http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/YourProject/Service1/?singlewsdl
```

the wsdl file that is created from your example code, you will find the following:

```
  <xs:element name="Ping">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="channelManager" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Either over [mex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-MetadataExchange) or as you see above in the wsdl. you get `xs:anytype` (in practical terms the c# object). This behavior although frustrating is to be expected, Mex and the `WsdlExtractor` only understand concrete types - DataMembers denoted by a `[DataContract]` in the service arguments, well that or simple types. Any other will be treated gracefully as 'object' rather then just failing to compile.

The philosophy part:

Effectively you are trying to pass a method `[ServiceContract]` as a parameter. Services (with their logic built to IL in some DLL) do not serialize and pass over networks - not because it can't be done - because it is not what they are for.

In your example `IChannelManager` is a `[ServiceContract]`, and you even try to export the `Ping()` as an `[OperationContract]`. the `[ServiceKnownType]` attribute does nothing to remedy that.

When is the `[ServiceKnownType]` useful then? Well that is well [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167(v=vs.110).aspx) but the gist of it is - if your DataMember in runtime is to hold some concrete class - that the compiler cannot infer at compile time (e.g. interfaces, abstract classes or base classes) well then a deserializer will not be able to guess what concrete types it should **know** when trying to deserialize.

You might then say to me - well that sounds fair and well but I *need* to pass my logic (Service) as a parameter. And to that I'd say - what you need is to redesign your solution. Maybe write and host more services and use the service equivalent of the [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) or [Delegation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) patterns.

I hope some of this helps.