# Interface as parameter in WCF REST Service

Tags: c#, rest

Unable to deserialize  Interface in WCF REstful service

```
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(CDMAnnotationRequest))]
    public Interface IdocumentService
    {
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Annotation", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
            [OperationContract(Name = "AddAnnotation")]
            [FaultContract(typeof(FaultData))]
            ICDMAnnotationResponse AddAnnotation(ICDMAnnotationRequest annotationReq);
    }
```

Above is my Service AddAnnotation that accepts Interface type as parameter. Below is the Interface Structure which inturn incorporates another Interface attribute.

```
public interface ICDMAnnotationRequest
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the document id.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The document id.</value>
        string DocumentId { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the page GUID.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The page GUID.</value>
        string PageId { get; set; }
        ICDMTextStampAnnotationData TextStampAnnotationData { get; set; }
    }
```

When I post data to service it gives me Error:

> Unable to caste "System.Object" to Type "Interface".

I have tried everything, but I am missing something I guess. And My project is pointing to .Net Framework

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310160/passing-interface-in-a-wcf-service

Comment: thanks Soner. Can you please tell me if My parameter has nested Interface. what could be done. I have added KnownType for all concrete classes